# User is sometimes not authorized to perform action on AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

```
{
  "Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet on resource: $my-elastic-search-domain"
}
```

Is a message I get when I `GET` to my AWS Elasticsearch instance but sometimes I get the actual result that a permitted user would get. It's pretty much 50/50.

I recently updated my access policy and I have 2 nodes - is it propagating the changes to the other node or something? Is there some caching going on? Maybe because I'm behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: I have fixed it for now by creating a whole new ES instance with only 1 node. Maybe it was the way it was configured.

Comment: Experiencing the same thing today, getting the "not authorized" error seemingly at random. This is after deleting and re-creating the index, if that makes any difference. EDIT: Not at random, it is exactly every 2 requests that it fails. Two successes, two failures, two successes, ad infinitum.